# My android app runs in eclipse emulator but doesn't run on my device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

The titles explains, when I try to run my app on my phone eclipse give me an error message about classpath source, please any help

That's my code and it's running perfectly on the AVD
Even when I export the apk file it runs on the android virtual device but when I install it on my phone device the application unfortunaly stops

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="TextView" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="application.android.news2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="application.android.news2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public void a(){



     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://test002.herobo.com/Index2.php");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        html = str.toString();


        String newStr = html;

        newStr = newStr.replace("<", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace("!", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace("-", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace(":", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace("/", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace(">", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace(".", "");
        newStr = newStr.replace("=", "");
        String s='"'+"";
        newStr = newStr.replace(s, "");

        String delStr = "Hosting24 Analytics Code script typetextjavascript          


                srchttpstatshosting24comcountphpscript End Of Analytics Code"; 

        newStr = newStr.replace(delStr, "");




        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView2.setText(newStr);



}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing Network in the Main Thread, which is not allowed. Read [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask) to learn how to use AsyncTask for this.

Comment: I used asynctask and I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your AVD is pre Android 3.0, and that your device is Android 3.0 and above, and that you are running into a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, since you `a()` method is called directly from `onCreate()`, and does network operations.

Try moving your networking code into a background thread or an AsyncTask.

Comment: I used asynctask and I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you should not call a() method in MainThread, please follow below code to call a() method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new LoadDataTask ().execute();
}

private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return a();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        refreshTextView(result);
    }
}

public String a() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://test002.herobo.com/Index2.php");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }

    String html = "";
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str == null ? "" : str.toString();
}

private void refreshTextView(String newStr) {
    newStr = newStr.replace("<", "").replace("!", "").replace("-", "")
            .replace(":", "").replace("/", "").replace(">", "")
            .replace(".", "").replace("=", "");
    String s = '"' + "";
    newStr = newStr.replace(s, "");
    String delStr = "Hosting24 Analytics Code script typetextjavascriptsrchttpstatshosting24comcountphpscript End Of Analytics Code";
    newStr = newStr.replace(delStr, "");
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2.setText(newStr);
}
```

Comment: it isn't working since the textView is in another activity ( MainActivity) and I tried to use intent to transfer data to the main acitivity it's giving errors

Comment: what do you mean? you can write one callback method to refresh MainActivity's UI since you hava got the real data.

Comment: TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); in the refreshTextView method is giving an error

Comment: you can define a global variable and call findViewById() in onCreate() .but  refreshTextView() method runs in UI Thread, what's the error information? please paste it, ok?

Comment: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LoadDataTask

Comment: you can define a global variable and call findViewById() in onCreate() , do you try this ? LoadDataTask is a inner class in Activity, it's abnormal, because onPostExecute runs in UIThread. you can find some useful tips through this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You are getting the error because you are in a nested class and do not have access, due to the difference in scope, to methods defined in the outer class. You need to fully qualify the class to use its methods.

Comment: It didn't work yet :/ maybe I didn't use the global variables in the correct way

Comment: Finally it worked with asynctask, but it worked only in avd and I still have the same problem when debugging on my phone